# Sympy substitutions using strings subs('x', 'w') instead of symbols subs(x, w)

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm working on an application with a circuit simulator [ahkab](https://github.com/ahkab/ahkab), and long story short I need to substitute the laplace variable s in some equations with 1j*w.  It is much more convenient for me to perform this substitution and others using the names of symbols rather than the symbols themselves.  I have come across some odd behaviour.

If you do

```
    >>> x = Symbol('x')
    >>> y = Symbol('y')
    >>> expr = x + y
    x + y
    >>> expr.subs('x', 'w')
    w + y
```

Which seems to work as I expect.  The problem comes with the symbol is declared with complex = True, here

```
    >>> s = Symbol('s', complex = True)
    >>> y = Symbol('y')
    >>> expr = s + y
    s + y
    >>> expr.subs(s, 'w') #Works as expected
    w + y
    >>> expr.subs('s', 'w') #Has no effect, this is my problem.
    s + y
```

I haven't been able to find information about substitutions in this manner in the docs.  To me this seems like a bug, but I don't know what the behaviour should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subs` calls `sympify` on it arguments.  See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/basic.py#L845 for example.  This means that strings will be converted to symbols but `sympify` has no way of knowing that you want your strings to be converted to symbols with non-default assumptions.  The only way to do that is to actually pass in the symbol.  Note that symbols with different assumptions are not considered equal.

```
In [1]: from sympy import Symbol

In [2]: x = Symbol('s')

In [3]: y = Symbol('s')

In [4]: x == y
Out[4]: True

In [5]: y = Symbol('s', complex=True)

In [6]: x == y
Out[6]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you keep track of all Symbol instances in a dictionary. You may make a specialized dictionary e.g.:

```
from sympy import Symbol as _Symbol

class SymbolCollection(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = _Symbol(key)
        return value

symbs = SymbolCollection()
def Symbol(key, *args, **kwargs):
    s = _Symbol(key, *args, **kwargs)
    symbs[key] = s
    return s
```

applied to your example:

```
>>> s = Symbol('s', complex = True)
>>> y = Symbol('y')
>>> expr = s + y
>>> expr
s + y
>>> expr.subs(s, symbs['w'])
w + y
>>> expr.subs(symbs['s'], symbs['w'])
w + y
```

If the solution is too verbose I would suggest writing a specialized `subs` function and pass `expr` explicitly as first argument instead of relying on the method `.subs`